# Changing tuple in list in dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
D = {'A':
        [ ( '1','2' ), ( '3', '4' )],
     'B':
        [ ( '5','6' ), ( '7','8' ) ]
    }

x = '6'

for key in D:
    for val in D[key]:
        if x in val:
            val=('50','60')
        
print(D)
```

Hello, I want to make a change at the value of key B, but I wonder why it does not print this:

```
    D = {'A':
            [ ( '1','2' ), ( '3','4' ) ],
         'B':
            [ ( '50','60' ), ( '7','8' ) ]
        }
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 3):

By doing `val=('50','60')` you replace the variable itself, not the content of the list.

```
for d_val in D.values():
    for rank, val in enumerate(d_val):
        if x in val:
            d_val[rank] = ('50', '80')
```

Comment: You could improve on this by iterating on `D.values()`, because you don't need the keys at all.

Answer (score 0):

`val` is a local reference to the element. When you overwrite it, you just assign a new tuple to that variable - it has nothing to do with the list that contains it. Instead, you could loop of the list's indexes and update the list directly:

```
for key in D:
    for i in range(len(D[key])):
        if x in D[key][i]:
            D[key][i] = (50,50)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary comprehension to get this done in one line.

Here's your code to define the dictionary `d` and value `x`

```
d = {'A':
        [ ( '1','2' ), ( '3', '4' )],
     'B':
        [ ( '5','6' ), ( '7','8' ) ]
    }
x = '6'
```

The below one line of code will create the dictionary `d` again with the new value. To show you that `d` and `r` are different only by a small difference, I have retained dictionary `d`.

```
r = {k:[(50,60) if x in i else i for i in d[k]] for k in d.keys()}
```

To ensure there is only one change, I am printing both `d` and `r`.

```
print (d)
print (r)
```

The output will be as follows:

```
{'A': [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')], 'B': [('5', '6'), ('7', '8')]}
{'A': [('1', '2'), ('3', '4')], 'B': [(50, 60), ('7', '8')]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuples cannot be edited. There you go! Have a nice day!

Comment: I dont think the OP is asking to change the value of a tuple. Instead OP is asking to replace an item in the list. Read the question properly.